# Sessions no PHP

Tags: php, session

Estou trabalhando num sistema que tem um 'filtro geral' de buscas na tela inicial. Pra isso, no meu cabeçalho coloquei um select/combo box e um botão 'OK'.

Pra tratar isso eu resolvi usar sessions, onde posso guardar o valor que o cara escolheu e usar em todas as páginas necessárias. Só que essa session tá apresentando um problema.

-Cada vez que ele vai pra alguma outra página, a session parece que zera e eu não tenho mais a informação:

```
    session_start();        
    $geral = $_GET['slcGeral'];
    $_SESSION['Geral'] = $geral;
```

-Pra testar eu passei o valor direto e assim funciona normal:

```
    session_start();        
    $geral = 1;
    $_SESSION['Geral'] = $geral;
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: Onde estão esses códigos que você pôs na pergunta? Não dá para ter idéia de como você está usando nem a sessão nem guardando os valores da forma que você se expressou. Tente [edit] a pergunta de modo a ela ficar autosuficiente com os detalhes fornecidos, para aumentar a chance de ter uma resposta que resolva seu problema. Sugestão de leitura: [ask]

Comment: Primeiro verifique se a get esta setada, só então defina a session.

Comment: um isset resolveria tranquilo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se você sempre setar o valor de `$geral` igual a `$_GET['slcGeral']` quando a GET vier vazia vai limpar a session... Você deve primeiro checar se a GET esta setada, para então definir a session:

```
session_start();        
if (isset($_GET['slcGeral'])) {
    $geral = $_GET['slcGeral'];
    $_SESSION['Geral'] = $geral;
} else {
    $geral = $_SESSION['Geral'];
}
```

Sugiro ainda padronizar o nome da variável para evitar confusão:

```
session_start();        
if (isset($_GET['geral'])) {
    $geral = $_GET['geral'];
    $_SESSION['geral'] = $geral;
} else {
    $geral = $_SESSION['geral'];
}
```

OBs.: Isso implica modificar também o nome do campo no formulário ou URLs dos links.